# Preventing UINavigationController from adjusting origin when status bar is hidden in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have a series of `UINavigationControllers` inside a `UITabBar` controller. I want to hide the status bar. When I do this however, the navigation bar adjusts itself to become shorter:

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xjnM.png)

[image]

How can I prevent this and get something like the picture below?

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX45d.png)

[image]

Currently I am just hiding the status bar using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom UINavigationBar with a custom sizeThatFits.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNavigationBar)
  - (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,64);
    return newSize;
  }
@end
```

if any queries comments pls

Comment: Setting the height to `64-[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height` seems to work, but results in some stuttering when changing the status bar

Comment: set height to navigation bar not in status bar

Comment: No, I understood that. But using a fixed height of 64 results in an 84px tall navigation bar when the status bar is not hidden. Hence, we need to subtract the height of the status bar to get a consistent 64px

Comment: God iOS 7 can be annoying

Comment: why want navigation bar size increase

Comment: because in ios 7 status bar 20px nav 44px total nav bar size 64. if you hide status bar 64-20=44 px for navigation bar. why want exactly any special reason

Comment: I need it to always be a total of 64, regardless of whether there's a status bar or not

Comment: The reason for this is so I can put temporary status information (alerts, etc) into that 20px space without disrupting the rest of the UI

Comment: Works with the edit suggested by OP. Still not the optimal solution though, hiding the status bar with an animation stutters.

Comment: I think there are overlays that position themselves above statusbar using extra window.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. It makes nav bar higher when status bar is not hidden.

Comment: above answer works above question. every different problems have different solution don't compare the solution for your problem @huoxinbird

Comment: @codercat I apologize for not reading the question clearly. I thought jaggedcow had a series of nav controllers and wanted to hide only one of them instead of all. Your answer is very smart and inspires me to find a solution for my problem.

Comment: tell or post your question and then fwd question to me @huoxinbird

Comment: then why put minus vote to me can to plus @huoxinbird

Comment: I really want to change it but SO does not allow me to undo downvote @codercat

Comment: edit the answer and undo your votes/upvotes @huoxinbird

Comment: You can edit the answer and I will undo the downvote. @codercat

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Container View inside your Storyboard and set a fixed Top Space (same as status bar). You could embed your `NavigationController` in this View then.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6GWy.png)

[image]

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk5mO.png)

[image]

I hope this helps.

Edit: Added Images

Comment: Do you mean embed the UITabBarController?

Comment: This, or the specific UINavigationController. It depends on your needs. It's just an idea and maybe there is a nicer solution out there.

Comment: And this can't be fixed using Autolayout?

Comment: In your pictures, the navigation bar still has a height of 44px, not 64 as desired. You've simply moved the 20px gap from the bottom to the top

Answer (score 2):

**In appDelegate.m - create navigation controller and set it to root view controller**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{       
       UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


        HomeViewController *homeViewController = (HomeViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

        return YES;
}
```

**Then instead of navigation bar you can re-create navigation bar by using UIImageView + label + button etc...**
 
Then you need to give correct autosize mask so that UIImageView adjusts itself properly 
 
[image: Custom navigationBar]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of codercat's answer. When status bar is hidden, the `origin.y` of navigation bar is 0. In this case, I set it's height to 64. When status bar is not hidden, keep the default height 44.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNavigationBar)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGPoint originInWindow = [self.window convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:self];
    CGFloat height = originInWindow.y > 1 ? 44 : 64;
    return CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, height);
}
@end
```